# Add 'Checked' to a Radio Input via JQuery on var = True?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

Have some javascript that takes a timestamp and breaks it up into hours and minutes, converting 24-hour time to 12-hours

```
// convert to 12-hour clock
if (hours > 12) {hours = hours - 12; am = false;};
if (hours == 12) {hours = hours; am = false;};
if (hours == 0) {hours = 12;};
```

The following code works, but there must be a better practice for simply adding the `checked` element

```
var am = true;

if (am == true) {$('#amRadio').html(am1);};
if (am == false) {$('#pmRadio').html(pm1);};

var am1 = '<input type="radio" name="ampmRadios" id="ampmRadios" value="AM" checked>AM'
var pm1 = '<input type="radio" name="ampmRadios" id="ampmRadios" value="PM" checked>PM'
```

Any recommendations for better practice?

Comment: What's wrong with creating the html like that? You could use `createElement` or `$("<input />")` and set the properties, but it will do the same.

Comment: use two inputs with different id's then try if(am==true){$("#amRadios").attr(checked,"checked");}else{$("#pmRadios").attr(checked,"checked");}

Comment: @tymeJV thanks for the createElement

Comment: @shyamnathan where should the first checked be defined?

Answer (score 0):

If all you're doing is trying to check/uncheck an element, use the jQuery prop() method:

```
$('#amRadio').prop('checked',true); //false to uncheck
```

[edit] note, based on the above id='amRadio' would need to be the id of your radio INPUT, not the container it currently references. Also, note that the IDs of your two radio buttons should be different, not the same as you have them.  Only the name="" attribute of the radio buttons should be the same.